# CodeIgniter -> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

i have been using xampp as localserver . when i try to run my code that time it will give a error -> "  Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: core/CodeIgniter.php

Line Number: 518 "

also give one more error " A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1044): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'stud'

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 203

Backtrace:

File: /opt/lampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once "

```
code --> 
` $db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'stud',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE /*(ENVIRONMENT !== 'production')*/ ,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);    
`
```

Comment: The error says access to mysql is denied, most likely it caused by you have a wrong mysql username and / or password, try to change it, also username cannot empty

Answer (score 0):

Step #1. Change the username to 'root' or what ever you configured and run the code.

Step #2. If you are still facing the issue, changes the password from '' to the one which you entered at the time of MySQL installation and run the code.

Step #3. If you are still facing the issue double check the database username and run the code.

Step #4. If you are still facing the issue, please find the port number on which MySQL is running and configure.